# angular material select hangs up

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I am using angular material V1.1.1 and angular js version 1.3.13.I have used **md-select** to select a value from dropdown. When I click on **md-select** , it shows the md-options value but hangs the whole screen and i am unable to click anywhere in the page as it adds a md-scroll-mask .I am not sure what causes the problem.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have loaded the angular-aria and animate references correctly

```
 <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <script  src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script  src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular-aria.js"></script>
```

[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Y9AVm8JjKwFdn3nOM2Up?p=preview)

Comment: Since i have less reputation numbers , it won't be marked as correct.

Comment: @Asra you can click the tick mark which appears next to the answer